# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

Tags: python

i try to train.py in object_detection in under git url

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

However, the following error occurs.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

So I tried to solve the problem by writing the following code.

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/user/Documents/imgmlreport/inception/models/research/object_detection')
from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
```

This problem has not been solved yet.

The directory structure is shown below.

```
~/object_detection/train.py

~/object_detection/builders/dataset_bulider.py
```

and here is full error massage

> /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/**init**.py:34: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated.
>
> In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
>     from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "train.py", line 52, in 
>       import trainer
>
> File"/home/user/Documents/imgmlreport/inception/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 26, in 
>       from object_detection.builders import optimizer_builder
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

how can i import modules?

Comment: Are you sure that your directories are at "/home/user/Documents/imgmlreport/inception/models/research" and not at "~/Documents/imgmlreport/inception/models/research"?

Comment: yes. The absolute path of the directory was checked.

Comment: oh, sorry but i don't understand your comment. was i write '~/Documents/imgmlreport/inception/models/research' ? absolute path in's work?

Comment: Yes. Please try that.

Comment: it still does not work. error massage is equal upper massage

Comment: i find out that is so simple problem. i just made own setup.py and setup directory files. then it'swork

Comment: Please elaborate. Which directories did you make and what did you add to setup.py file?

Comment: write details to answer.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try install **Tensorflow Object Detection Library Packaged**

```
pip install tensorflow-object-detection-api
```

Comment: This one also is the way to solve the import error for "string_int_label_map_pb2"

Comment: This is only for tensorflow 1.x version not 2.x.

Comment: @hyunwooCho I got around that issue on Windows 10 by copy-pasting Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection into the package directory in AppData/../object_detection. Still figuring out how to do the same for Colab

Answer (score 4):

Cause of this error is installing object_detection library, So one of the solution which can work is running the below command inside models/research

```
    sudo python setup.py install
```

If such solution does not work, please execute the below command one by one in the directory models/research

```
    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
    sudo python setup.py install
```

I hope this will work. I also faced the same problem while creating model from export_inference_graph.py. It worked for me.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. If anyone have an error with `sudo python setup.py install`, please consider method at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md#python-package-installation.

Comment: Thanks @CloudCho. If you run into trouble installing `pycocotools` you may need to install the `python3-dev` package.

Answer (score 3):

You need to export the environmental variables every time you open a new terminal in that environment.

Please note that there are are back quotes on each of the pwd in the command as this might not be showing in the command below. Back quote is the same as the tilde key without pressing the shift key (US keyboard).

From tensorflow/models/research/

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

Comment: what do you mean by From tensorflow/models/research/?

Answer (score 1):

try this:
python setup.py build
python setup.py install

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of modules in the object_detection folder, and I have created setup.py in the parent directory(research folder) to import all of them.

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup


REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['Pillow>=1.0', 'Matplotlib>=2.1', 'Cython>=0.28.1']

setup(
    name='object_detection',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=[p for p in find_packages() if p.startswith('object_detection')],
    description='Tensorflow Object Detection Library',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did have "sys.path.append()" before you imported the object detection, so I am surprised that you are facing this error!

Please check that the path you have used in sys.path.append() is right.

Well, the only and obvious answer for the error is that the path of the module is not added properly.

Besides the various ways mentioned here, here is a way in which you can add the "object_detection" path permanently to the PYTHONPATH variable.

If you are using a Linux system, here is how you would go about it:

Go to the Home directory. Press Ctrl + H to show hidden files. You will see a file called ".bashrc". Open this file using a code editor (I used Visual Studio).

In the last line of .bashrc file, add the line:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/your/module/path:/your/other/module/path:your/someother/module/path
```

Then press "save" in the code editor. Since ".bashrc" is a "Read-only" file the editor will throw a pop-up saying the same. Also in the pop-up there will be an option that says: "Try with sudo". Hit this button and now you are good to go.

All your modules are now **permanently** added to the PYTHONPATH. This means that you need not run sys.path.append every time you open your terminal and start a session!

Below is the screenshot with no error when I followed the said steps:

[image]

Try this. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

And finally, If you've followed all the steps here and are at your wit's end...make sure the file that you're running (the one with your source code in it ya know), isn't named `object_detection.py` - that would preclude it being searched for as a module.

Certainly I've never done anything like this that led me to add an embarrassing answer on Stack Overflow...

Answer (score -1):

I had to do:
`sudo pip3 install -e .` ([ref](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2031#issuecomment-343782858))
`sudo python3 setup.py install`

System:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04, Anaconda (I guess this is why I need to use `pip3` and `python3` even I made virtual environment with Pyehon 3.8)