# Installing tensorflow object_detection api in a repo in google drive

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, modulenotfounderror

I have cloned the [models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) repo from TensorFlow and installed it into my project folder in google drive.

but when I try to run the `model_builder_tf2_test.py` I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'` error.

```
import sys
nb_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/project/lib'
sys.path.insert(0, nb_path)
```

and installed it using the following command

```
!python -m pip install --target=$nb_path .
```

the files are downloaded into the project folder but can't be accessed by the files in `models` repo.

however, I can access the modules using the:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/drive/MyDrive/project/lib')
```

The error I am getting after running:

```
%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/project/models/research
!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
```

is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment but still don't have enough reputation.

did you try using this?

```
  pip install tensorflow-object-detection-api
```

if it helps,
believe the question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113683/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-object-detection)?